# Nativescript-VideoPlayer in Angular 2

Tags: angular, nativescript

This question might be more general to just including NPM plugins in a Nativescript mobile application but I will use this particular plugin as an example.  I have followed through the documentation for adding third-party plugins from the Nativescript site, but I still can't seem to get this plugin to work with my mobile app using Angular 2 and Nativescript.

I installed the plugin using:

```
tns plugin add nativescript-videoplayer
```

Here is my component:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { Video } from 'nativescript-videoplayer';


@Component({
    selector: "grandhall",
    templateUrl: "pages/grandhall/grandhall.html",
    styleUrls: ["pages/grandhall/grandhall-common.css", "pages/grandhall/grandhall.css"]
})

export class GrandHallComponent {

}
```

Here is my template:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label text="Grand Hall"></Label>
    <VideoPlayer:Video id="nativeVideoPlayer" controls="true" autoplay="true" height="280" src="https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" />
</StackLayout>
```

This is what plugin documentation says I need to do to show a video in my mobile application, but the video is not showing on the page.  I am also testing this on an actual device iPhone 6 Plus and not in the emulator.

I am guessing that there is something I need to do differently to include the View from the plugin in my Angular 2 template.  Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `registerElement` like this:

`// somewhere at top of your component or bootstrap file
import {registerElement} from "nativescript-angular/element-registry";
registerElement("VideoPlayer", () => require("nativescript-videoplayer").Video);`

Then it is usable in your UI and from the NativeScript Angular documentation: https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/plugins/angular-third-party.html#simple-elements

Comment: Thanks for the response Brad.  I went through that documentation before I posted here and tried what you have suggested above, but it still wasn't showing the video in my app.  Here is what I have now

Comment: Component: `import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Video } from 'nativescript-videoplayer';

import { registerElement } from "nativescript-angular/element-registry";
registerElement("VideoPlayer", () => require("nativescript-videoplayer").Video);

@Component({
 selector: "grandhall",
 templateUrl: "pages/grandhall/grandhall.html",
 styleUrls: ["pages/grandhall/grandhall-common.css", "pages/grandhall/grandhall.css"]
})

export class GrandHallComponent {
} `

Comment: I will look through the documentation some more to see if there is something I may have missed.

Comment: https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-videoplayer/issues/15#issuecomment-225711693 this was working and I know it still is because Blake another contributor uses it with AngularNative and he tested last week. So it's likely something else going on with your layout possibly.

Comment: Hey Brad thanks for pointing me in the right direction here.  I don't know why I didn't think to look at the closed issues on the Github page.  The one you have referenced in your comment above has resolved the issue for me.